# How to fill with similar colours?

Tags: color, icon, color-reproduction, compression, jpg

I have this image that have been damaged by JPG, and would very much like to restore it, as if it had never been compressed with JPG.

[image]

Can someone help me with this? I assume I need to fill with similar colours to get the sharp edges back?

Comment: Is that shown at 100% or is it enlarged for clarity?

Comment: @e100 I have just found a better version and inserted that instead. But yes, it is shown at 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this image is representative of your other images, with large, flat areas of color, then a simple color quantize can give a good result.  In the sample images there are only three intended colors: two shades of grey, and yellow.

Open the image in Photoshop, and choose Image > Mode > Indexed Color

Set:

- `Colors`: 3
- `Forced`: None
- `Transparency`: Unchecked
- `Dither`: None

Then, select `Palette`: Custom...

Change the three colors to:

`363636`
`f8df2c`
`282325`

And apply.  You should get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to use `Select > Color Range`:

- Eyedropper a clean area of the yellow to make it the foreground color. Be sure to set the sampling to 3x3 or 5x5, not single pixel.
- Choose `Select > Color Range` and click the "+" icon in the dialog. Work with the image until all the icon pixels are selected but none of the background (should be easy).
- Ctl/Cmd-J to copy the selected area to a new layer.
- Add a layer below this and fill with black.
- You can Zoom in and clean up any rough bits with a single-pixel eraser tool, but I suspect that won't be necessary.